# Jenkins fails while copying the repo despite correct credentials

Tags: jenkins, build, bitbucket

unfortunately my build fails every time.

The copy process is apparently always supposed to fail. 
But this user on Jenkins has 100% access to the repo. 
I can exclude this error to 100%.

Does anyone know what caused it?

```
        using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials for Bitbucket Notifier plugin and Nexus service
     > git.exe fetch --tags --progress -- https://URL/bitbucket/test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
    ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
    ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
   ....
    stderr: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
    remote: Counting objects: 1           
    remote: Counting objects: 4198, done.        
    remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/2939)           
    ...          
    remote: Compressing objects:  99% (2935/2939)           

    ...
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here :

> ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
>
> ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

What you have to do is, update your SCM configuration where you have put down Bitbucket Repo details. There will be a setting for "timeout", its set to 10 be default if I remember correctly.

You can keep it blank so that timeout won't occur.

Comment: Do you think the error occurs because copying takes longer than 10 minutes and then there is a timeout?

Comment: Yes, Multiple reasons. Incorrect credentials, really large repository, network issue/bandwidth problem etc. I had encountered same issue when Git server was hosted totally in different region than specific Jenkins slaves.